# Custom Filename for ALAsset while adding to ALAssetGroup

Tags: iphone, ios, alassetslibrary, alasset

I was able to create custom album using [link](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/)

So from my application when I save file(image or video) they get added to my custom folder.
I also need to give functionality to display all the saved files.

So I am using "enumerateAssetsUsingBlock" to enumerate and fetch files from my custom folder.
Only problem that I am facing is that, the filename that I am retrieving is not the same as that of file I had added.

```
ALAssetRepresentation* representation = [result defaultRepresentation];
[representation filename];
```

gives me filename like : IMG_0261.mp4 which is not the original filename of file that I had saved. How can I get real file information?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the original filename unfortunalely. 
The AssetsLibrary changes the filename on import to one of the pattern IMG_XXX.ext. The original filename is lost.

Comment: Is there a way to name the file?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't.